# How to call Visual Studio Native prompt from powershell without starting new procesw

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to automate my build process and to do that, I want to call both x64 and x86 native code command prompts from my script.

The bat file is located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

and the code inside is:

@call

"%~dp0vcvarsall.bat" x64 %*

I want to know if there is a way to call it directly into the powershell process or alternatively, pass a parameter to a bat file ie cmd.exe / k something.bat (swap cmd for native tool)

Cannot figure it out so all help is appreciated

Comment: Obviously there's a `vcvarsall.bat` which can be called with an `x64` parameter. If you look into `vcvars32.bat` you'll see that there's an `x86` parameter as well. You can call `vcvarsall.bat` directly and pass that parameter

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795993/why-does-msbuild-fail-when-run-from-app-built-in-visual-studio-2019 .  However, the usage of Process in that post needs improvement. For usage of Process see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451991/query-user-called-via-cmd-exe-results-0-output/70452809#70452809