# How to run a command in cmd or power shell from C#/.NetCore?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, command-line, process

I am trying to execute a command in Command line from Visual Studio console application. But the code is just staring the new command line window. I want to execute the command and close the command window after execution. The parameter is another exe path along with some parameters.

```
string command = "some command";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.Arguments = command;

using (Process exeProcess = new Process())
{
    exeProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
    exeProcess.Start();
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Why are you executing cmd.exe rather than the actual exe directly?

Comment: The 3rd part exe should run from cmd or power shell with the parameters.

Comment: @Ullan If it's a console application it will open its' own console window, run, then close. You can still pass parameters, etc. Are you 100% certain you need to wrap that in a command shell or PowerShell? What's your use-case?

Comment: I trying to test the functionality in a console application. After that I will make this app as  a windows service. Yes, I have to run the 3rd party exe in either command line or windows power shell.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452809/10024425

Comment: Try running `cmd /?` at the command line. Read up on `cmd /c` and `cmd /k`