# ProcessStartInfo Arguments didn't work in C#

Tags: c#, process

```
 [HttpGet("tickets")]
 public IActionResult GetTickets()
        {
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @".\mysample.exe",
                Arguments = @"https://sample.domain.co.jp/api/test",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false
            };

            var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
            process.Start();

            process.WaitForExit();
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            ApiTicketsResponse response = new ApiTicketsResponse();
            response.code = 1;
            response.message = output;  

            return Json(response);
        }
```

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localhost:7244/MfApi/tickets' \
  -H 'accept: */*'
```

It returned. so `output` in my process didn't work.

```
{
  "code": 1,
  "message": ""
}
```

When I try to run `mysample.exe` it returned like `500 : (500) Internal Server Error https://sample.domain.co.jp/api/test`

So I expected to respond like that. But actually they didn't respond anything.

```
PS C:\Users\h-miyashita\Downloads> .\mysample.exe https://sample.domain.co.jp/api/test
500 : (500) Internal Server Error https://sample.domain.co.jp/api/test
```

What is the root cause of them ?
If someone has opinion, will you please let me know. thanks

Comment: If the process is producing an error, maybe you're looking for `process.StandardError` instead of `process.StandardOutput`?

Comment: Probably you should debug the _mysample.exe_ with that argument to see what is the problem.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452809/10024425