# Process.Start() - Both see and redirect output

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm using process to run a command line program.
When it runs from a command line it tells you where it is in the process of running, which can take a few hours, and occasionally gets stuck part way through.

It would be really nice to be able to see that output while the program is running.
But I also want to capture that output and store it so I can go over it later and look to see if it threw an error or anything, which means I think it has to have RedirectStandardOutput set to true, and UseShellExecute set false.

How do I have my cake and get to look at it too?

```
            Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(ScriptPath, args)
            oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            oStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
            oProcess.Start()

            Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
                sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
                If sOutput.Contains("Job complete without errors") Then
                    UpdateRecord(ID, sOutput)
                End If
            End Using
```

Comment: It will be simpler to let the command Programm refirct the output into a text file `> myputput.txt` and have a timer read the file periodically

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846819/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452809/10024425

Comment: @nbk the issue with grabbing the output and piping it to a form element like a text box is that it's running the script multiple times in parallel, and if all the outputs were sent to a textbox at the same time it would be very confusing. It would be better to have multiple process windows each with their own output.

Comment: then you must open for every start a new tab with unique named textbox,a and give every outputname the same  unique name so that the correct texbox is filled, so you have for all its iwn text box, where you can see what happens