How to I pass parameters to an .exe file when I send via explorer.exe using C#
I need to start a new process without administrator privileges from a process with administrator privileges.
I was using explorer.exe to send the process.
e.g.:
var p = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = "explorer.exe", Arguments = $"\"{exeFileToRun}\"}};
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

The problem I am facing is that I can't pass parameters to the exeFileToRun.
If I try this:
var p = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = "explorer.exe", Arguments = $"\"{exeFileTorun}\" {cmdArgs}" } };

I get windows explorer instead of the exe being executed.
I tried it in cmd windows and i get the same results.
How can I pass command parameters to an exe which is sent by explorer.exe?

Aside: why use Explorer at all?

You may consider reading the documentation for System.Diagnostics.Process and ProcessStartInfo - your efforts seem misguided. Start with ProcessStartInfo.FileName

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452809/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846819/10024425

This is intentionally misusing explorer. The command line parameter is supposed to be a folder, not a file. And definitely not parameters. You can translate Shell Execute From Explorer to C#.

The question as asked is really about how arguments/switches to explorer.exe are interpreted.
If you pass a folder as the single argument to explorer.exe, Windows Explorer will open at the specified folder.
If you pass a file instead, Explorer will attempt to launch the file. In the case of an executable, the executable will be run. This is why your first code excerpt works - almost as a side effect of Explorer's behaviour.
But there is no support in explorer.exe for accepting additional arguments for propagation to that executable, so I believe the answer to your question is "you can't" - and as per the comments, I am not sure why you would want to.
There are more details about Explorer's command-line switches here, although these are almost certainly beyond the scope of what you are trying to do.
A better approach might look something like this:
var process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.FileName = exeFilePath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdArgs;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; // See note below

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

Note: For the relevance of the UseShellExecute property, see this StackOverflow question.
If this solution isn't appropriate for your requirements, it would be helpful if you could explain why not and clarify what you are trying to do.
